# Send BCC mailx without seeing primary email

Tags: python, email, mailx

I am sending email from a python script using the mailx function.

```
mailx -r my@email.addr -b foo@email.addr,bar@email.addr blackhole@email.addr
```

This works fine, however the foo and bar recipients recieve the email as a conversation with my email and the blackhole email.  I have tried only including the BCC addresses, but I get the following error.

```
"Send options without primary recipient specified"
```

Is there a way to send an email like this where the BCC recipients only see the sender's address?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that `mailx` can be invoked without a `to-addr`; however, you could certainly repeat the `-r` address there:

```
mailx -r my@email.addr -b foo@email.addr,bar@email.addr my@email.addr
```

Or you could use a dummy address:

```
mailx -r my@email.addr -b foo@email.addr,bar@email.addr notARealAddress@notARealDomain.com
```

but that will cause your MAILER-DAEMON to send you an error email in reply.  (And if the recipients try to reply to it, it will also cause them to get error emails.)